# clockwork recovery not working

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode

I cannot use the "recover" tool. I have the same issue as this post: [Why isn't Clockworkmod Recovery "Sticking"?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18932/why-isnt-clockworkmod-recovery-sticking) but I am unable to rename the file described as it is not shown in the directory. I think this may be because I do not have root access. What should/can I do next to get on with installing a new custom OS?

Comment: What kind of phone? What version of Android?